# Initializing a Clear function in JS Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a JS calculator and am working on an allClear function. I created a clear function, which is stored in a class Calculator. Outside of the function I am creating an event listener to call the function and it is not working. I am confused because it seems to be working for the two other elements above, specifically, I am calling updateDisplay() above and the proper information is being passed. Any information to help me understand why my allClear function is not working would be helpful.

```js
const allClear = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]');
const del = document.querySelector('[data-delete]');
const number = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]');
const operand = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operand]');
const equals = document.querySelectorAll('[data-equals]');
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]');
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]');

class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined
  }

  delete() {

  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    if (this.currentOperand.includes('.') && number === '.') return
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand + number
    console.log(this.currentOperand)
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    this.operation = operation
  }

  compute() {

  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand
    this.operation = this.operation
    console.log(this.operation)
  }
}


const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

number.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})

operand.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})

allClear.addEventListener('click', function() {
  calculator.clear()
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="output">
      <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
      <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
    </div>
    <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
    <button data-delete>DEL</button>
    <button data-operand>÷</button>
    <button data-number>1</button>
    <button data-number>2</button>
    <button data-number>3</button>
    <button data-operand>*</button>
    <button data-number>4</button>
    <button data-number>5</button>
    <button data-number>6</button>
    <button data-operand>+</button>
    <button data-number>7</button>
    <button data-number>8</button>
    <button data-number>9</button>
    <button data-operand>-</button>
    <button data-number>.</button>
    <button data-number>0</button>
    <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
  </div>
</body>
```